# Type suffix puts me in a fix

Tags: lotusscript

In Lotusscript (IBM Notes version 9), I wanted to open a file for reading and another for writing. So, I wrote the code:

```
Dim readFileNum, writeFileNum As Integer
# .....
readFileNum% = Freefile() #Line 1
Open "C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\raw.txt" For Input As readFileNum% #Line 2
writeFileNum% = Freefile()  
Open "C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\refined.txt" For Output As writeFileNum%
```

I could not get lines 1 and 2 compiled, as the error message "Type SUFFIX does not match datatype readFileNum" kept flashing. But the next two lines on **writeFileNum%** did not generate any error. After getting advised through one of the Internet tips, I had to remove the **%** sign in Line 1 and Line 2 to get past the error.

But, it appears to be cutting the Gordian knot. Secondly, what is the privilege that **writeFileNum%** has that was refused to **readFileNum%**? Conversely, what is the sin committed by the latter that the former is innocent of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is serendipitous. I just split the declaration **Dim readFileNum, writeFileNum As Integer** to two separate lines as:

```
Dim readFileNum as Integer
Dim writeFileNum as Integer
```

and voila, the error message disappeared. Appears silly and I can't help this self-assessment.

Comment: This is NORMAL. The line `Dim readFileNum, writeFileNum as Integer` will make readFileNum a Variant and writeFileNum an integer. To do this in one line you would have to write `Dim readFileNum as Integer, writeFileNum as Integer`